# extraReducers -> builder.addCase() typescript error (Redux Toolkit)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to using RTK and typescript and I have a problem with (Property 'pending' does not exist on type '() => Promise  >') in my extraReducers. I don't see any similar situation online as mine and suspect I am missing something very simple. However, I can't seem to find it.

It's my axios api call function:

```
export const getUser = () =>
  apiCallWithAuthToken.get<UserResponse>("users/me");
```

My AsyncThunk:

```
export const getUserData = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/getUser", async () => {
    const response = await getUser();
    return response.data;
  }
);
```

Types and initial state:

```
interface userState {
  id: string;
  walletAddress: string;
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  reflink: string;
  createdAt: string;
  modifiedAt: string;
  isLogged: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
}

const initialState: userState = {
  id: "",
  walletAddress: "",
  email: "",
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  reflink: "",
  createdAt: "",
  modifiedAt: "",
  isLogged: false,
  loading: false
};
```

it's my store:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userSlice, { getUserData } from "./features/user/userSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userSlice,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      thunk: {
        extraArgument: getUserData,
      },
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
})
```

and it's my slice:

```
export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getUser.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    })
  }
});

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

I got a typescript error, why? Error image below:[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg6sp.png)

Comment: Did you mean to check `getUserData.pending`?

Comment: OMG, thanks. Works well! :)